# merge two sorted arrays without built in ruby function

Tags: arrays, ruby, algorithm, sorting

Im trying to merge two sorted arrays without using any build in sorting methods. Here is what I have so far.

```
def merge(array_1, array_2)
    i = 0
    k = 0
    merged_array = []
    while i < array_1.count && k < array_2.count
        while k < array_2.count && array_1[i] > array_2[k]
            merged_array << array_2[k]
            k += 1
        end
        merged_array << array_1[i]
        i += 1
    end
    merged_array
end

array_1 = [5,8,9,11]
array_2 = [4,6,7,12,13]

p merge(array_1, array_2)
```

The input is   `array_1 = [5,8,9,11]` and `array_2 = [4,6,7,12,13]` and the output is suppose to be `[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]`.  Can someone please explain why its not working. Thank you!

Comment: You may want to use `Array#shift` instead of iterating, just `array_1.dup` and manipulate your copy. I'm not sure this method will work in its current form.

Comment: Or create enumerators and use `peek` and `next`. Merge sort goes back to the age of tapes and can thus be implemented using enumerators only.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this

```
def merge(array_1, array_2)
  return enum_for(__method__, array_1, array_2) unless block_given?

  a = array_1.each
  b = array_2.each
  loop { yield a.peek < b.peek ? a.next : b.next }

  # Your code is not working because the equivalent of these two lines
  # is missing. After you reach the end of one array you have to append
  # all remaining elements of the other array. I am doing this here by
  # just exhausting both enumerators, one of which is empty by now.

  loop { yield a.next }
  loop { yield b.next }
end

p merge([5, 8, 9, 11], [4, 6, 7, 12, 13]).entries
```

No need to keep track of indices. Merge sort goes back to the age of mainframes and tapes and can thus be implemented using enumerators only.

How does this work?

- `each` creates enumerators
- `peek` returns the next element without advancing the enumerator
- `next` returns the next element with advancing the enumerator
- both of the above raise `StopIteration` when they reach the end of the enumerator
- `loop` repeats a block of code until `StopIteration` is raised

Comment: `> array_1 = [5,8,9,11]`
`> array_2 = [6,4,7,12,13]`
`> merge(array_1, array_2)`
 `=> [5, 6, 4, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13]`

:(

Comment: @AlexGolubenko: From the question : `two sorted arrays`

Comment: I was looking for a rescue clause in your code. I didn't know for `loop` and `StopIteration`. Nice!

Comment: I really like your enumerator based approach. You could also _return_ an enumerator, using `yield` instead of `c <<`.

Comment: @Stefan great suggestion! Updated.

Answer (score 1):

One could insert the elements of one array into a copy of the other array, using [Array#bsearch_index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-bsearch_index) to determine where each element of the first array should go.

```
def merge(array_1, array_2)
  array_2.each_with_object(array_1.dup) { |n,arr|
     arr.insert(arr.bsearch_index { |i| i>n } || arr.size, n) }
end

array_1
  #=> [5, 8, 9, 11] 
array_2
  #=> [4, 6, 7, 12, 13, 14] 

merge(array_1, array_2)
  #=> [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

This is O(n<sub>1</sub>*log(n<sub>2</sub>)), n<sub>1</sub> and n<sub>2</sub> being the sizes of the two arrays, so it would be more efficient for the loop to be over the smaller of the two arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
def merge_array(arr1, arr2)
  result = []
  l1, l2 = arr1.size, arr2.size
  m, n = 0, 0

  while true
    break if arr1[m].nil? || arr2[n].nil?

    if arr1[m] < arr2[n]
      result << arr1[m]
      m += 1
    else
      result << arr2[n]
      n += 1
    end
  end
  result += arr2[n..-1] if arr1[m].nil? && n < l2
  result += arr1[m..-1] if arr2[n].nil? && m < l1

  result
end
```

Compare with method uses Kernel#loop

```
                   user     system      total        real
```

merge_array_loop   0.349738   0.002263   0.352001 (  0.352043)

merge_array_new    0.075791   0.002874   0.078665 (  0.078680)